# spacy: how to get lemma-based PhraseMatcher

Tags: python, spacy

I want to find a phrase words from which has the same lemma, for example if I search for "cat runs", it should match "cats ran". I tried to create a new doc with words lemma-free, but I need dependencies for some reason, but the new doc doesn't contain dependencies, and I can't match indexes of the new doc and the old doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PhraseMatcher supports matching on attributes other than the text, so you don't need to build an extra Doc:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
nlp = spacy.load('en')
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LEMMA")
matcher.add("CAT", None, nlp("cats run"))
matches = matcher(nlp("cat ran")) # [(14858270728821099472, 0, 2)]
```

(I don't think the non-English spacy models or the Stanford models use the `-PRON-` lemma, so I don't think you need that extra check. If you do need to modify lemmas, you can just modify them in place in an existing Doc: `token.lemma_ = token.lemma_.lower()`. As you already have in your example, be sure that the text doc and the phrase doc provided to the PhraseMatcher are modified in the same way.)